# Paste for Mac using WebdriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to only paste something from my clipboard using `webdriverIO`. I can do this successfully on a windows pc using **Control** and **v**, but it doesn't work on Mac using **Command** and **v**. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue with Chromedriver.

Found that I can use the alternative past keys for Mac. Sending in **Shift**, and **Insert** did the trick.

More info here https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=30